# getxattr operation not supported samba audit

Tags: ldap, samba, smb-conf

I have a strange issue with my samba ldap server, its a centos server with same 3.0, it was working fine from quite some time but suddenly I noticed that my log file is full of messages saying **getxattr operation not supported samba audit**..and it goes upto some TBs. If i comment vfs_object then it works fine but it doesn't log audit msgs which I dont want to be skipped.
couldn't find a way around.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your samba shares reside on a filesystem without xattr support (or mounted with the noxattr mount option)?

Comment: Yes, this filesystem is ext3 and it doesn't support xattr, but it was running from the beginning, and if doesnt support xattr, what is the way around to get rid of this msg?

Comment: Ext3 supports xattr, you should simply mount it with the **user_xattr** mount option.

Comment: I remounted the filesystem with user_xattr but showing me the below logs:   Apr 16 16:40:50 user smbd_audit: USER|IP|getxattr|fail (Operation not supported)|.//s.jpeg|user.SAMBA_PAI

Comment: Have you restarted samba? Have you installed xattr user-space utilities and library? If issuing `getfattr -d <filename>`, what you see?

Comment: yes i had restarted samba several times, log messages file flooded with this type of entries, for same IP its showing this error for all files placed in the shared folder, then again it goes for next IP and hit error for all files. Getfattr returns nothing. Can I share you the screenshot in any means to have a better idea about the same? What is this user.SAMBA_PAI means?

Comment: One more thing I noticed, let say I have opened the shared drive, then this error is shown for all the files and folders placed in that directory, again when I open any subdirectory, error logged for all the files and folders in subdirectory. And this is happening for the all the users in organization.

Answer (score 0):

Though its not a good solution but you can skip this failure error from smb.conf file by just changing the log failure to exclude this getxattr option.